# Go through a list of cells with strings and compare it to another list in excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops, string-comparison

I have a list of 60 text strings with corresponding values in excel, lets call it list A and I need to go through another list of 2000 textstrings, lets call it list B and compare them to each other. What I want is a column beside list B with the values from list A. Like this:

[image: Example picture of the excel sheet]

Comment: This is pretty standard VLOOKUP.  Google that and you will get many tutorials on how to use it.

Comment: I'm not really used to solve problems like this in excel but I managed to solve it with a Matlab script instead. Thanks a lot anyways I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Enter the below formula in `B2` and drag down,

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,D:E,2,FALSE),"")
```

[image]